# regexp взять meta теги php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь взять мета-теги со страницы, в которых есть html разметка, например:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Ecology, allelopaty, Corn Cokle <em>(Agrostemma Githago L.)</em>, germination viability, sprout, ramified root, chlorophyll content, yield, varietal fruit colour, antocyan, digestion, resistance against pests and diseases, resistance against climatic extremes, organic food production.">
```

таким regexp `<meta( .*?>|>)`. Это приводит к обрезанию части ключей. Я понимаю, что это возможно не валидный код, но мне нужно взять мета, есть ли какая то возможность сделать это regex-пом или нужно предварительно подготовить строку? Помогите составить регулярку, если это возможно.

Comment: [`~<meta.+>~`](https://regex101.com/r/SIPXXa/1) ?

Comment: Нет. Тильда `~` в шаблоне - это обычный ограничитель. А всё дело в жадности квантификатора +.

Comment: блин, в этом и проблема, если тег скрипт перенести к последнему >, то он также захватывается, нужно зацепить именно закрывающий тег мета

Comment: Пример покажите, плиз.

Comment: попробуйте этот текст ```<meta name="keywords" content="Ecology, allelopaty, Corn Cokle <em>(Agrostemma Githago L.)</em>, germination viability, sprout, ramified root, chlorophyll content, yield, varietal fruit colour, antocyan, digestion, resistance against pests and diseases, resistance against climatic extremes, organic food production."><style type="text/css">``` т.е. нужен не просто >, а именно мета, в этом проблема, если перед регуляркой использовать strip_tags, то она не корректно вырезает тег em из моего примера

Comment: проверил, так же получается, если следующий стайл прикрепить к первому ```<meta name="keywords" content="Ecology, allelopaty, Corn Cokle <em>(Agrostemma Githago L.)</em>, germination viability, sprout, ramified root, chlorophyll content, yield, varietal fruit colour, antocyan, digestion, resistance against pests and diseases, resistance against climatic extremes, organic food production."><style type="text/css"><style type="text/css">``` я не могу писать в чате, не знаю почему

Comment: по сути регулярке нужно пропускать столько >, сколько есть < внутри мета, но возможно ли это регуляркой?

Comment: А если так: https://regex101.com/r/SIPXXa/4

Comment: :) тут дело в том, что <style - это пример, там может быть любой тег, в том числе и не валидный, например ```</br>```

Comment: Любой тег, кроме <em> ?

Comment: <em> в том числе, я прохожу по сайтам и чего там только нет

Comment: Ну тогда наверное вот этот вариант вам и подойдёт: https://regex101.com/r/SIPXXa/5

Comment: такие варианты не поправимы? мета может быть пустым и после него допускаю, что может быть любой символ ```<meta>
<meta name="keywords" content="Ecology, allelopaty, Corn Cokle <em>(Agrostemma Githago L.)</em>, germination viability, sprout, ramified root, chlorophyll content, yield, varietal fruit colour, antocyan, digestion, resistance against pests and diseases, resistance against climatic extremes, organic food <production.">op<style type="text/css"><style type="text/css">``` нашёл решение в ```$v = explode('<meta', $v);
  $v = array_map('strip_tags', $v);
  $v = implode('<meta', $v);```

Comment: может оно надёжнее? пока тестирую

Comment: @Эдуард, неа, если внутри два тега, будет фигня.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы так должно получиться:

```
<meta\s("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])*>
```

Проверка:

```js
s = '<meta name="keywords" content="Ecology, allelopaty, Corn Cokle <em>(Agrostemma Githago L.)</em>, germination viability, sprout, ramified root, chlorophyll content, yield, varietal fruit colour, antocyan, digestion, resistance against pests and diseases, resistance against climatic extremes, organic food production."><style type="text/css">'
console.log(s.match(/<meta\s("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>])*>/)[0])
```